# Columns from datatable disappearing in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, dt

I have a problem with the DT::renderDatatable function, maybe someone can help. I am trying to display a data.table in a shiny app and it only shows the first 9 out of 14 columns. When I print the DT to the console it works fine.

```
 # load and render
     observeEvent(input$btLoadUserRules, {
    # get data.frame with user rules
    df.temp1 <- oFormUserRules$getAllUserRules()
    # convert to data.table
    dt.temp2 <- data.table(df.temp1)


    output$tbl_tab2_1 <- DT::renderDataTable(dt.temp2,
                                             options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE))
```

Thank you!

Marie

Comment: What happens if you add `print(ncol(dt.temp2))` in the `observeEvent`? Do you get 9 or 14 in the console?

Comment: Problem is solved. It wasn't that not all columns are displayed, but it was zoomed in so some columns were not visible anymore. I didn't notice that because it is not possible to scroll, so the only way to view it correctly was to zoom out. Thanks all!

Comment: where is the example?

Comment: The example is to render a DT with many columns on a small screen. May also depend on the browser, I used IE. You will see that you can't see all columns and no scroll bar appears. At least that was the case for me and a friend of mine ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't like what you're doing in `observeEvent` as you should ever do small things within `observe` statement. Perhaps this alternative will work?

```
dt.temp2 <- eventReactive(input$btLoadUserRules, {
        # get data.frame with user rules
        return(as.data.table(oFormUserRules$getAllUserRules())))
output$tbl_tab2_1 <- DT::renderDataTable(dt.temp2(),options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)))
```

Comment: thank you, it already works now as i just commented above. still i will consider your code to make mine better.

Comment: you might run into issues if you use `observe` in such a way so better to use `reactive` expressions :) happy coding